# socket.io проблема с переподключением

Tags: javascript, node.js, сокет, socket.io

Использую socket.io с node.js, проблема заключается в том, что соккеты бывает сами переподключаются, и потом на клиент все данные(одинаковые) приходят 2 и более раз, в зависимости от количества переподключений без обновления страницы, код взят из официальных доков, как решить данную проблему ?

```
/* client */
socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('start connect');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            switch(data.event){
                case 'start': connected(data); break;
                case 'error': alert(data.text); break;
                case 'online': online(data.type); break;
                case 'message': message(data.UsInfo, data.text);
            }
        });

});

/* server  */
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8081);
// Навешиваем обработчик на подключение нового клиента
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New connection :)");
    var ID = (socket.id).toString().substr(2);
    var time = (new Date).toLocaleTimeString();

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        var time = (new Date).toLocaleTimeString();
        switch(data.event){
            case 'start': start(socket, ID, data.steamid); break;
            case 'bet': bet(data, game, socket, ID); break;
            case 'message': message(data.text, ID); break;
        }

    });



io.sockets.emit('game', { event: 'game', number: winner, text: 'РОЗЫГРЫШ'});
```

Comment: Дайте больше информации, пример кода который вы используете для реализации связи node.js & socket.io

Comment: @Shnur, https://jsfiddle.net/vv4m9uhn/

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан, все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Comment: а при ошибке подключения, вы на клиенте не пересоздаете коннект? что-нибудь типа `socket.on('disconnect',...)`

Comment: @NumminorihSF, дело в том, что новый коннект автоматически создается, но старый не убивается, из-за этого по 2 и более раз приходят данные клиенту после обрыва, помогает только перезагрузка страницы

Comment: новый коннект создается вашим кодом или нет? если вашим - уберите его, т.к. в доке к socket.io написано, что автоматический реконнект происходит через 1 секунду

Comment: @NumminorihSF, я предоставил кусок моего кода, там нету коннекта при потере соединения, то есть реконнект делает сам socket.io, не могу понять в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы на каждое событие подключения создаете подписку, слушающую сообщения. А это событие создается даже при переподключении, т.е. вы имеете 1 сокет, на который при каждом переподключении навешиваются дополнительные слушатели сообщений.

Оставьте вместо `socket.on('connect',...)` на клиенте `socket.once('connect',...)`. Это позволит всего один раз реагировать на создание подключения.

Либо, вынесите `socket.on('message',...)` за пределы реакции на коннект, ничего страшного не случится.

Ну и самый веселый вариант - проверяйте ручками, что данную подписку вы создавали (например через булеву переменную), если 2 предыдущих варианта не устраивает.

Comment: Спасибо большое , ваш ответ решил проблему.